# TypeError: resolver is not a function [POST request]

Tags: next.js, axios, xmlhttprequest, sanity, next-connect

Hi guys this is my user registration api code

That trying to mutate sanity user document field

It's taking user's name, email, password

**All imports**

```
import { createRouter } from "next-connect";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import axios from "axios";
import { signToken } from "../../../../lib/auth";
```

**post request**

```
handler.post(async (req, res) => {
const projectId = "SOMETHING";
const dataset = SOMETHING
const apiVersion = "SOMETHING";
const tokenWithWriteAccess = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_TOKEN;
const createMutations = [
{
create: {
_type: "user",
name: req.body.name,
email: req.body.email,
password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password),
isAdmin: false,
},
},
];
```

**post request to sanity with mutations payload**

```
const { data } = await axios.post(
https://${projectId}.api.sanity.io/v${apiVersion}/data/mutate/${dataset}?returnIds=true,
{ mutations: createMutations },
{
headers: {
"Content-type": "application/json",
Authorization: Bearer ${tokenWithWriteAccess},
},
}
);
const userId = data.results[0].id;
const user = {
_id: userId,
name: req.body.name,
email: req.body.email,
isAdmin: false,
};
```

**passing the response to client**

```
const token = signToken(user);
res.send({ ...user, token });
});

export default handler;
```

[And i am getting this error and call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eys7B.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.